# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six' , Six is already installed

Tags: python, pip, six

I am trying to run this pretty simple text-to-speech program on my Mac:

```
# Import the required module for text 
# to speech conversion
from gtts import gTTS
  
# This module is imported so that we can 
# play the converted audio
import os
  
# The text that you want to convert to audio
mytext = 'Welcome to geeksforgeeks!'
  
# Language in which you want to convert
language = 'en'
  
# Passing the text and language to the engine, 
# here we have marked slow=False. Which tells 
# the module that the converted audio should 
# have a high speed
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
  
# Saving the converted audio in a mp3 file named
# welcome 
myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
  
# Playing the converted file
os.system("mpg321 welcome.mp3")
```

but when I try to run it I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Documents/University/Intro to Python/Random/texttospeech.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gtts import gTTS
  File "/Users/name/Documents/University/Intro to Python/Random/gtts/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .tts import gTTS, gTTSError
  File "/Users/name/Documents/University/Intro to Python/Random/gtts/tts.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import urllib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

The line 6 it seems to be referring to in tts.py is "from six.moves import urllib", if that matters. Running `pip show six` looks fine, with version 1.15.0 installed in python3.7/site-packages and I'm using IDLE version 3.7 as well so it doesn't seem like the problem is there. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling six, as well as `pip install --ignore-installed six` and `python -m pip install six` and while both run without issue, neither have fixed my problem. I don't know what else to try, can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Show us the output of this code: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with a virtualenv? Can you try and run pip -V to see you are using the right pip?
A common mistake is thinking that since the default environment variable for python points to a certain version then it is the same for pip. If you are not working under a virtualenv this might be the problem. I suggest adding more information about your issue as it can stem from many reasons